# Split variable in Pyspark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, data-wrangling

I try to split the utc value found in `timestamp_value` in a new column called `utc`. I tried to use the Python RegEx but I was not able to do it.
Thank you for your answer!

This is how my dataframe looks like

```
+--------+----------------------------+
|machine |timestamp_value             |
+--------+----------------------------+
|1       |2022-01-06T07:47:37.319+0000|
|2       |2022-01-06T07:47:37.319+0000|
|3       |2022-01-06T07:47:37.319+0000|
+--------+----------------------------+
```

This is how It should look like

```
+--------+----------------------------+-----+
|machine |timestamp_value             |utc  |
+--------+----------------------------------+
|1       |2022-01-06T07:47:37.319     |+0000|
|2       |2022-01-06T07:47:37.319     |+0000|
|3       |2022-01-06T07:47:37.319     |+0000|
+--------+----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with with a [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html) and [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html) respectively

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

(df
 .withColumn('utc', F.regexp_extract('timestamp_value', '.*(\+.*)', 1))
 .withColumn('timestamp_value', F.regexp_replace('timestamp_value', '\+(.*)', ''))
).show(truncate=False)

+-------+-----------------------+-----+
|machine|timestamp_value        |utc  |
+-------+-----------------------+-----+
|1      |2022-01-06T07:47:37.319|+0000|
|2      |2022-01-06T07:47:37.319|+0000|
|3      |2022-01-06T07:47:37.319|+0000|
+-------+-----------------------+-----+
```

To better understand what that regular expression means, have a look at this [tool](https://regex101.com/r/m0Lqvf/1).